# When testing logging in Django using testfixtures, how can I silence the log emission?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, logging

I'm using the LogCapture object from testfixtures to unit test logging statements.  Works wonderfully.

However, during my test suite, logs are actually being emitted to the console (messy for Jenkins) and, worse, to Sentry!

I don't want to have to override the LOGGING setting; this seems to undermine the test itself.  How can I prevent these emissions while still capturing logs?

Comment: Is this an option: check for `if 'test' in sys.argv:` in `settings.py` and turn off console and sentry loggers?

Comment: check my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255657/how-can-i-disable-logging-while-running-unit-tests-in-python-django/7732916#7732916

Comment: @Hassek: I love your answer (and looked at it before asking this question), but it doesn't apply to this scenario.  I don't want to disable logging precisely because I want to capture it for use in my unit test.  Instead, I want to simply silence emission.

Comment: oh interesting, if you ever find something about it let me know, but my wild guess is that you need to add that silence functionality to the logs configuration when the test begin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the mock library?

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock/

This will let you "fake" the call sentry and still track what it logs.