# Mocking an object in a distant module

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, monkeypatching

I have some unittests that I am running on a class, `ClassA`. This class has methods that call `ClassB`. `ClassA` and `ClassB` are in separate modules, `class_A.py` and `class_B.py`. Both of these modules have `logger` functions that are available globally within that module.

During my test of the methods of `ClassA` I want to suppress the logging messages. Using `mock.patch` it is straightforward to do this for the logger in `class_A.py`. But I have not found a way to patch the logger in `class_B.py`.

Here is some sample code:

**unittest_file.py**

```
import unittest
import class_A

class TestClassA(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_method(self):
        my_class_A = class_A.ClassA()
        my_class_A.run_method()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass
```

**class_A.py**

```
import logging
from class_B import ClassB

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class ClassA:

    run_method(self):
        my_class_B = ClassB()
        my_class_B.do_something()
        logger.info("Running method on Class A")
```

**class_B.py**

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class ClassB:

    do_something(self):
        logger.info("Doing something on Class B")
```

To patch the logger in `class_A.py` I can add `@patch('__main__.unittest_file.ClassA.logger', autospec=True)` as a decorator to the `test_method()` method.
But I don't have direct access to the logger in `class_B.py` to patch it as well.

The closest I have come to a solution is this:

`@patch(eval('__main__.unittest_file.class_A.ClassB.__module__')['logger'])`

but the `eval()` function applied to the module name doesn't preserve the import location, so it doesn't patch the logger in the right namespace.

I know I could easily solve this by changing the `import` statement in `class_A.py` to `import class_B` instead of `from class_B import ClassB`, but I don't want to edit the code in `class_A.py` or `class_B.py`, so that's not the answer I'm looking for.

I also know there are ways around this by disabling logging, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255657/how-can-i-disable-logging-while-running-unit-tests-in-python-django) but I am more interested in being able to fine-tune the control I have over different parts of the code to be tested, so that's not the answer I'm looking for either.

My question is:
Is there a way that I can navigate from an imported object to other objects in its parent module, while staying in the same namespace?

Comment: So you only want to patch the logger, but keep everything else?

Comment: For now, yes, I just want to control the log output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me simply patching `class_A.logger` and `class_B.logger` works, e.g.

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

class TestCaseA(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('class_A.logger')
    @mock.patch('class_B.logger')
    def test_method(self, mockedA, mockedB):
        my_class_A = ClassA()
        my_class_A.run_method()
```

Both loggers don't output log messsages anymore.

Comment: But the `unittest_file.py` module doesn't know anything about `class_B` so I can't patch it directly. The logger for `class_B` is only referenced through the namespace of `class_A`.

Comment: I just tried it and it works. Have you tried it out?

Comment: The arguments to unittest.mock are passed as strings-  and are resolved by importing the modules in the dottetpath as the test is run. This will work, unless the  `class_B.py` file cannot be found in the pythonpath when the test is run.

Comment: which is a pretty unrealistic scenario. did it work @berkelem?

Comment: Yes, it worked on the sample code I posted, but not on my original problem. After a little more digging I realized my sample code was not an accurate reflection of the issue I was having, because in my case I was not calling the logger directly, but through a decorator function. And it is not easy to patch a decorator because it is applied to the function on import. 
I'll accept your answer because it answered the question as asked. But just in case anyone has the same trouble I had, here is the answer that helped me solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37890916/4844311