# Django unittest handle PermissionDenied

Tags: python-3.x, django, unit-testing, django-2.2

As docs says https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#exceptions;

> The only exceptions that are not visible to the test client are `Http404`, `PermissionDenied`, `SystemExit`, and `SuspiciousOperation`. Django catches these exceptions internally and converts them into the appropriate HTTP response codes. In these cases, you can check `response.status_code` in your test.

I handle a custom a login mixin for raising an error to user logged in but has no access to that page.

```
class LoginQuizMarkerMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            if not self.request.user.has_perm('quizzes.view_sittings'):
                raise PermissionDenied("You don't have any access to this page.")
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

I my unitest, it working fine.

```
class TestQuestionMarking(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.c1 = Category.objects.create_category(name='elderberries')
        self.student = User.objects.create_user(username='student',
                                                email='student@rebels.com',
                                                password='top_secret')
        self.teacher = User.objects.create_user(username='teacher',
                                                email='teacher@jedis.com',
                                                password='use_d@_force')
        self.teacher.user_permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(codename='view_sittings'))

        ....


    def test_paper_marking_list_view(self):
        # should be 302 (redirection)
        marking_url = reverse('quizzes:quiz_marking')
        response = self.client.get(marking_url)
        print('response1', response)

        # should be 403 (permission denied)
        self.client.login(username='student', password='top_secret')
        response = self.client.get(marking_url)
        print('response2', response)

        # should be 200 (allowed)
        self.client.login(username='teacher', password='use_d@_force')
        response = self.client.get(marking_url)
        print('response3', response)
```

But for somehow, it the error of `PermissionDenied` it showed an error like this:

```
docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django python manage.py test labs.tests.quizzes.test_views.TestQuestionMarking.test_paper_marking_list_view


response1 <HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/accounts/login/?next=/quizzes/marking/">


WARNING 2021-02-04 00:28:44,270 log 1 139681767683904 [log.py:222] Forbidden (Permission denied): /quizzes/marking/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 75, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/my_app/quizzes/views.py", line 37, in dispatch
    raise PermissionDenied("You don't have any access to this page.")
django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: You don't have any access to this page.
response2 <HttpResponseForbidden status_code=403, "text/html; charset=utf-8">


response3 <TemplateResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

And what I expected is still capured as an error, not showing up like above. And should be like this below:

```
response1 <HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/accounts/login/?next=/quizzes/marking/">

response2 <HttpResponseForbidden status_code=403, "text/html; charset=utf-8">

response3 <TemplateResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

But, in another test when I try to change it with `raise Http404`, it worked fine:

```
class LoginQuizMarkerMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            if not self.request.user.has_perm('quizzes.view_sittings'):
                # raise PermissionDenied("You don't have any access to this page.")
                raise Http404
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

The console output:

```
response1 <HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/accounts/login/?next=/quizzes/marking/">
WARNING 2021-02-04 13:39:05,368 log 1 139683990402880 [log.py:222] Not Found: /quizzes/marking/
response2 <HttpResponseNotFound status_code=404, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
response3 <TemplateResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by disabling my logging inside settings for test mode.

```
docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django python manage.py test --settings=config.settings.test
```

and inside my `config/settings/test.py`;

```
LOGGING = {}
```

> Related issue: [How can I disable logging while running unit tests in Python Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5255657/6396981)