# Django sends web requests messages to my logging file

Tags: django, uwsgi

I want to cancel Django to show me those web server requests, it getting to my uwsgi.log file of my application and i can't find where to set it off.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5jCh.png)

I tried looking at the documentation of django but couldn't find

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable logging while running unit tests in Python Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255657/how-can-i-disable-logging-while-running-unit-tests-in-python-django)

Comment: sadly, not answering my question

Comment: Are you using uswgi as your wsgi server? If so you should check uwsgi documentation to fine-tune their logging level or even shut it down completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `disable-logging=True` in your `uwsgi.ini` file.

[Documentation Ref](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#disable-logging)