# How to simulate HTTP error 500 in django?

Tags: python, django

I have set a HTML page 500.html in my main direcroty.
It will show this page when `HTML 500 Internal Server Error` occurs.

How can I generate this error to check if it works?

I'm gussesing I should somehow raise exception of some sort.

How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test 500.html in (django) development env?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740003/how-to-test-500-html-in-django-development-env)

Comment: try this `return http.HttpResponseServerError()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try editing the urls.py as follows:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^500/$', 'django.views.defaults.server_error'),
    )
```

Then try accessing the page as follows:

http://localhost/500

http://yoursite.com/500