# How to run tests with `DEBUG=TRUE` in Django

Tags: python, django, pytest, django-testing

I am trying to write tests for my custom Error Page view:-
Docs can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/views/)

Also for writing test cases for i have included these urls as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page) :-

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^404/$', page_not_found_view),
        url(r'^500/$', my_custom_error_view),
        url(r'^400/$', bad_request_view),
        url(r'^403/$', permission_denied_view),
    ]

handler404 = page_not_found_view
handler500 = my_custom_error_view
handler403 = permission_denied_view
handler400 = bad_request_view
```

and views.py is :-

```
def page_not_found_view(request):
    t = loader.get_template('error/HTTP404.html')
    html = html = t.render({})
    return HttpResponseNotFound(html)


def my_custom_error_view(request):
    t = loader.get_template('error/HTTP500.html')
    html = html = t.render({})
    return HttpResponseServerError(html)


def permission_denied_view(request):
    t = loader.get_template('error/HTTP403.html')
    html = html = t.render({})
    return HttpResponseForbidden(html)


def bad_request_view(request):
    t = loader.get_template('error/HTTP400.html')
    html = html = t.render({})
    return HttpResponseBadRequest(html)
```

When i am hitting that urls manually i am getting proper response code  i.e `500` for visiting `/500` and so on.
Since those urls will be included only if `setting.DEBUG=True` by default and the test cases run in `DEFAULT=False` and  mode i tried to override it using `@override_settings` decorator

My test.py file is :-

```
@override_settings(DEBUG=True)
class ErroCodeUrl(TestCase):
    def test_400_error(self):
        response = self.client.get('/400/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 500)

def test_403_error(self):
    response = self.client.get('/403/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 500)

def test_404_error(self):
    response = self.client.get('/404/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 500)

def test_500_error(self):
    response = self.client.get('/500/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 500)
```

But using this `@override_settings` is not making any difference i am getting same assertion error with or without it. I am getting **404 status code** for every test i.e

For `test_500_error` :-
    response = self.client.get('/500/')
    AssertionError: 404 != 500

For `test_400_error` :-
    response = self.client.get('/500/')
    AssertionError: 404 != 400

*Note* :- The same error code '404`is returned when i visited these url with`DEBUG=False`.

Comment: Have you look at this answer 500

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/43139905/2581266][

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to test your 500

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import RequestFactory
from .views import my_custom_error_view

class TestMyErrorPages(TestCase):

    def test_error_handlers(self):
        factory = RequestFactory()
        request = factory.get('/')
        response = my_custom_error_view(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 500)
```