# pass variables to http404 django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass variables to the 404.html template. I am able to call 404.html but not able to pass any values. How can I do this?

I'd like to have something like this.

```
raise Http404({'error', 'acb_error')
```

Comment: Are you looking for the [`HttpResponseNotFound`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseNotFound)?

Comment: No, Just I am after throwing simple Http404 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out The `Http404` Exception [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception):

> For convenience, and because it’s a good idea to have a consistent 404 error page across your site, Django provides an Http404 exception. If you raise Http404 at any point in a view function, Django will catch it and return the standard error page for your application, along with an HTTP error code 404.

Here is the example usage from the docs:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from polls.models import Poll

def detail(request, poll_id):
    try:
        p = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
    except Poll.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Poll does not exist")
    return render_to_response('polls/detail.html', {'poll': p})
```

**Edit:**

Realized that this won't work for you unless you have `DEBUG = True`; therefore, you can use something like:

```
return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Error</h1><p>acb_error</p>')
```

Also, check out the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812470/django-custom-handler404-shows-404-but-gives-header-200) for tips on passing custom data to a standard 404 page.